# "Error: Could not find or load main Class S" while installing hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I am facing the below error

```
Error: Could not find or load main Class S
```

Initially, I had `JDK 11(Amazon Corretto)` on my system for other subject assignments.

I did set `JAVA_HOME` to `JDK11` location it was under Program Files, tried with a short name(PROGRA~1).

Also, In `hadoop_env` file `JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%`
Still, same issue persisted.

Tried uninstalling `JDK 11` and installed `jdk1.8.0_241`. Followed all the steps again but still, issue persists.

Tried adding Jar files to YARN file as mentioned in the below link :

["Error: Could not find or load main class" when starting Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680615/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-when-starting-hadoop)

[What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Tried setting classpath, but still the same error shows up.

Comment: Hadoop requires Java 8, by the way. But have you tried within a Linux VM?

Comment: Yes, it works on Linux VM.

Comment: Okay, what does `hadoop classpath` return?